# nhibernate paging The column '...' was specified multiple times for 'query'

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, pagination

I have an error "The column 'Translat2_' was specified multiple times for 'query'" when using paging for my query.

My classes hierarchy:

```
Politician
--PoliticianInFactions : PoliticianInFaction
--EntityTranslations : Translation

Faction
--PoliticiansInFaction : PoliticianInFaction
--EntityTranslations : Translation

Translation
--Name : String
--Language : Language
```

What I want: to fetch politicians ordered by its faction's name and than by its name. 
My query:

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Politician>("politician");

// criteria for current faction
var currentFactionCriteria = criteria
    .CreateCriteria<Politician>(x => x.PoliticianInFactions, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add<PoliticianInFaction>(x => x.FromDate <= DateTime.Now)
    .CreateCriteria<PoliticianInFaction>(x => x.Faction, JoinType.InnerJoin);

// add order by faction's name !!!
currentFactionCriteria
    .CreateCriteria<Faction>(x => x.EntityTranslations, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add<Translation>(x => x.Language.Id == languageId)
    .AddOrder<CityTranslation>(x => x.Name, Order.Asc);

// add order by politician's name !!!
criteria
    .CreateCriteria<Politician>(x => x.EntityTranslations, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add<Translation>(x => x.Language.Id == languageId)
    .AddOrder<Translation>(x => x.Name, Order.Asc);
```

When adding paging to this query I have an error. Without paging everything is OK. Also if I comment(remove) any block marked with (!!!) exception dissapears. 
What am I doing wrong? If this is a bug of NHibernate give me some workaround please. Thank you.

Comment: If your using NHibernate Lambda Extensions I *think* I had a similar bug when using two columns of the same name. Have you tried writing it just using the Criteria API?

Answer (score 0):

Check you mapping files to see if you have mapped multiple properties to the same database column or mapped the same databases column to multiple properties.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an ancient thread, but this issue plagued me recently.

I've discovered that the case of the property calls in your mapping matters relative to paging. I.E. if you have a property with a column called "field" and you map it to another property as well, this will not be an issue if the case of field is the same.

However, if you identify your other mapping with a column called "Field", paging will not know that this is not a distinct property and will try to query the same column twice!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a CASE or duplicate problem.In my issue I have the following situation:

[image]

I take the column "serie id" two times but in different ways.. I put "S" in lower and in upper.. I hope that helps..